# Prefixed Environment Variables in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, windows, environment-variables, asp.net-core-webapi

Actually, this question came as I was digging into configuration settings in .NET 6. I have set up system environment variables to be used in Production windows server. According to MS documentation, `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` extension method need to be used if we want to read system environment variables. Therefore I have modified my Program.cs (Main()) as below.

```
 var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json",optional:true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

And I read whatever the environment variables like this

```
var conString = configuration["DBConnection:ConnectionString"];
```

This is all good. Everything work as expected.

My question is, even if I remove `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` extension method it works. It's because, .NET gives higher priority to environment variables (correct me if I'm wrong). Also, please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Then I was looking at what other things can be done with `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`. Actually it can be used to setup prefixed environment variables like this
`.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix:"P2:")`, and I have set up my prefixed env variable as `P2__Name` also another env variable as `Name`. I'm reading that value as

`var name = configuration["Name"];`

When I run the api it will always read the value of `"Name"` env variable. Not `"P2__Name"` value.
What I'm doing wrong. Isn't it supposed to return the prefixed env variable value?

**p.s.** I have multiple .net applications to be hosted in a single windows server. All of them have dbConnection string in `appsettings.json`. I want to remove those from `appsettings.json` and keep them as environment variables

Answer (score 3):

As for your `P2__Name` and `Name` environment variables:

> Environment variables set with the `MyCustomPrefix_` prefix override the default configuration providers. *This includes environment variables without the prefix*.

The prefix will NOT be a part of the configuration key! So both will have the `Name` configuration key and according to the documentation the value of `P2__Name` environment variable should override the value of the `Name` configuration key.

Your prefix is suggested to end with a single underscore char (`_`).

The colon character (`:`) and the double underscore string (`__`) are hierarchy separators (they have nothing to do with your prefix), see the [Configuration keys and values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-keys-and-values) section.

> In environment variables, a colon separator may not work on all platforms. A double underscore, `__`, is supported by all platforms and is automatically converted into a colon `:`.

To have a prefixed connection string see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#connection-string-prefixes) whether one of the special prefixes suits your needs or not.

You can also use your custom prefix.

```cs
// Option #1: custom prefix: MyCustomPrefix_ (Key: "A1")
// MyCustomPrefix_ConnectionStrings__A1=AbcConnectionString

// Option #2: special prefix: CUSTOMCONNSTR_ (Key: "A2")
// CUSTOMCONNSTR_A2=CustomConnectionString

// Option #3: special prefix: SQLCONNSTR_ (Key: "A3")
// SQLCONNSTR_A3=MssqlConnectionString

// Option #4: special prefix: MYSQLCONNSTR_ (Key: "A4")
// MYSQLCONNSTR_A4=MySqlConnectionString

// Option #5: special prefix: SQLAZURECONNSTR_ (Key: "A5")
// SQLAZURECONNSTR_A5=AzureSqlConnectionString

IConfiguration configuration =
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables("MyCustomPrefix_")
        .Build();

string myCustomPrefixedConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("A1");
string customConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("A2");
string mssqlConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("A3");
string mysqlConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("A4");
string azuresqlConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("A5");
```

To sum up:

- custom prefix: `YourCustomPrefix_ConnectionStrings__YourKey`
- special prefix: `...CONNSTR_YourKey` where `...` can be `CUSTOM`, `SQL`, `MYSQL` and `SQLAZURE`

To get the connection string, only `YourKey` is needed:

```cs
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("YourKey");
```

Answer (score 1):

After wasting time figuring out why I can't read my prefixed variable, I've discovered another important point to note.

When using this code:

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json",optional:true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(config);
```

We are injecting to our application an *IConfigurationRoot*, but we **SHOULD** inject an *IConfiguration* to later correctly read a prefix variable. This would be the correct code:

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json",optional:true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(config);
```

> I have not yet been able to discover the reason, but this only works
> in certain environments since in others we must continue using
> *IConfigurationRoot*...